# Which method is better for reordable divs - Up/Down arrows or drag/drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

From an end user point of view. If I have a list of vertical divs with different content in each div, should I provide up/down arrows to reorder the divs or should I allow the user to drag and drop the divs into a particular order?

**Drag and drop** would allow the user to place the div anywhere in the vertical list but may not be obvious to the end user that the divs are movable.

**An up/down arrow** beside each div would provide visual cues but would be awkward for the end user if they wanted to move a particular div up or down by a large number of places.

In relation to the above, I am biased towards drag/drop due to my use of Moodle for teaching. We did have a training course which overcame the visual cue issue. I'm aiming my app to be as user friendly as possible without having to teach the user too much (if anything).

**Is there a particular CSS styling for a div that provides a cue - like a gripper hand to drag and drop and can I place some kind of visual cue around the div using CSS.**

Any input is most welcome and I hope you understand what I'm trying to achieve here.

**P.S. The vertical list can be quite long.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get some better answers to the usability questions on the [User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/). My own anecdotal experience having used an interface where items could only be moved up or down one item at a time in a long list was that it was a *total pain*, and when drag-and-drop was finally implemented, it was a breath of fresh air.

I also have conducted a usability test (task 1 [in this PDF](http://oerpub.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/usability-report-cnx-conference-03.pdf)) where a simple label of "Drag to add a new ..." (it was a duplication interface, not a reordering interface) on top of some pill-shaped elements (with a "grabby hand" cursor and change of color on hover) was quickly discovered by 8 out of 8 users without any prompting.

As for your technical questions, there are a few different CSS cursor styles you could implement (in particular, `cursor: move;`, `cursor:grab`,`cursor:grabbing` (my preference is for 'grab' on hover and 'grabbing' while dragging). I've shown some here: https://jsfiddle.net/xnho95oL/, as well an idea for some "placeholder" elements that might appear (and could presumably expand or otherwise change appearance when dragging an item over them).

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks Max. I was leaning towards drag and drop anyway but you've sealed the deal for me. Thanks for the suggestions and the pointers related to user cuing. @Max-Starkenburg